# PHP Regular Expression Help

Tags: php, regex

I would like to be be able to use a regular expression in PHP to be able to extract the value of
"Ruby9" from the following html snippet

```
on Red Hot Ruby Jewelry<br>Code: Ruby9<br>
```

Sometimes the "Code" will be alphanumeric,numeric, or just letters.

Any advice would be much appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
$str = "on Red Hot Ruby Jewelry<br>Code: Ruby9<br>";

$pattern  = "/Code: ([^<]+)/"; // matches anything up to first '<'
if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    $code = $matches[1]; // matches[0] is full string, matches[1] is parenthesized match
} else {
    // failed to match code
}
```

Comment: This works for what I posted. But how would I accomodate different types of strings like?         Coupon Code: SILVER - Use your Gap Silver Card or Gap Silver Visa Card and you'll save with free shipping on your entire order. Enter this code at checkout to see your savings.

Comment: basically need to prevent your code from extracting everything and anything after the "SILVER"

Comment: This works better "Code: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" to support both cases.

Comment: One last question: How to strip the "Code: XXXX" out of the string and return just the rest of it e.g" "on Red Hot Ruby Jewelry<br><br>" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=: ).+(?=<)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    // ow right! match!
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    // my bad... no match...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is always the same the regular expression would be like this:

```
"<br>Code: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)<br>"
```

That will capture any alpha or alphanumeric or just numeric string following a 
Code: and before a 
. Try the following:

```
<?php
$subject = "on Red Hot Ruby Jewelry<br>Code: Ruby9<br>";
$pattern = '<br>Code: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)<br>';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```